# How to provide a type hint for parameters whose arguments should be ordered and hashable?

Tags: python, python-typing

I want a type hint which indicates that the arguments are ordered and hashable.

```py
def foo(bar: OrderedHashable) -> None:
    ...
```

Here is my work in progress.

```py
from collections.abc import Hashable
from typing import TypeVar

OrderedHashable = TypeVar('OrderedHashable', bound=Hashable)

def foo(bar: OrderedHashable) -> None:
    ...
```

So far this still says nothing about ordered except in the name of the type `OrderedHashable`. How do I write such a type so that it really indicates that such instances should have ordered dunder methods such as `__gt__` or `__lt__`.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70698000/workaround-for-lack-of-intersection-types-with-python-generics).

Comment: I'd probably just create a protocol with the methods you want. For comparisons, I think you technically only require `__lt__` and `__le__`, and then you could have the protocol inherit `Hashable`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate That sounds promising. Feel free to post an answer using that approach. Otherwise I will read [PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the way `sorted` is defined in pylance, I think it just needs to support less than `__lt__` and greater than `__gt__` to be sortable. In the example below I've adjusted the bound on your TypeVar to require the addition of these methods:

```py
from typing import Hashable, Protocol, TypeVar

class OrderedHashable(Hashable, Protocol):
    def __gt__(self, other: "OrderedHashable"):
        ...
    def __lt__(self, other: "OrderedHashable"):
        ...

OrderedHashableT = TypeVar('OrderedHashableT', bound=OrderedHashable)

def foo(bar: OrderedHashableT) -> None:
    ...
```

Note that the function signature in the final function should contain a reference to the type `OrderedHashableT` in the return, but I've kept it this way for consistency with the question. Hope this helps!